# Get value from UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I can't get initial value from `UIPickerView`.

Here is some code:

```
.......
#define kMaximumPlayers 15
......
   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) 
        {
            self.totalPlayersPossible = [NSMutableArray array];

            for (int x = 2; x < kMaximumPlayers; x++) 
            {
                [_totalPlayersPossible addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
            }
        }
        return self;
    }


    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.totalPlayersPossible objectAtIndex:row]];


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.pickverView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    }
 }
```

When I run the app first row of `UIPickerView` is selected. The problem is that I can't get the value of that row:

```
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
//here I get the value of selected row

       [self setNumberOfSelectedPlayers:[[self.totalPlayersPossible objectAtIndex:row]intValue]];
    }

The value of setNumberOfSelectedPlayers is 0.
```

What I miss here ?

Comment: Where are you 'getting' the value of the selected row ?

Comment: What you mean about where I get the value ?

Comment: I don't see the code where you're 'getting' the value for the selected row.

Comment: Did you map the IBOutlet in Interface Builder?  Sometimes this is the reason code such as this fails to work as you might expect.  Also, I don't see where you are getting any value out of the UIPickerView either.  In `viewDidLoad` you are setting the UIPickerView value, but that is not the same as getting the value.  Please make your Question / intent more clear.

Comment: It seems to me that self.totalPlayersPossible is not being retained. What is your @property declaration for that?

Answer (score 3):

As Novarg says, the `didSelectRow:` message is not called on load. You can call the `pickerView: titleForRow: inComponent` message directly, though, to obtain the title of the currently selected item at any time. Assuming the title you want is in the first "reel" (component) of the picker view:

```
NSString *initialTitle = [self pickerView:self.pickerView
                              titleForRow:[self pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]
                             forComponent:0 
];
```

This assumes self serves as the UIPickerViewDelegate for the pickerView, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first time you see that `UIPickerView` the method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

does not get called because you did not select it. That method is only called when you effectively select a row(scroll and select one of them).

Hope it helps